# Is RDS instance in 'pending reboot' status after parameter group change automatically rebooted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I changed a parameter in a MySQL 8.0 RDS instance parameter group.

I chose the `pending-reboot` apply method to avoid downtime, and now the parameter group is marked as "pending reboot" in the configuration tab of the rds instance.

So I was wondering: given that my rds instance specifies a maintenance window, will it be automatically rebooted during such maintenance window?

Or will I have to reboot it myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be automatically rebooted during the maintenance window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking at this question in the future, the instance was not restarted.

As far as I understood from the documentation, maintenance windows only apply to Amazon-issued maintenance.

Comment: This may also be useful: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-maintenance-window/.  It says here that parameter group changes you've chosen not to apply immediately are also applied, however, it seems a restart isn't guaranteed.   Hence the recommendation to manually reboot.

Answer (score 0):

pending-reboot for RDS instance we must reboot manually. maintenance window will not take care of it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30355073)